# Catching YouTube video going fullscreen in extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, google-chrome-extension, youtube

As starter in Chrome extensions i'm trying to triger my function when somebody puts his youtube video into fullscreen. I've came up with code below, but it still don't triggers the alert message.

Manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Ext",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Catching fullscreen.",
"icons": {"16": "icon_16.png"
        },
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"browser_action":{
    "default_title": "Ext",
    "default_icon": "icon_16.png"
},
"permissions": [
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var link = document.getElementByClassName('ytp-fullscreen-button');

link.addEventListener('click', function() {
     alert("Fullscreen");
     });
});
```

Beside answering to question how to add custom listener to video going fullscreen event i would be very thankful for some tips how to improve myself in this type of apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [extensions architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): background page of an extension is not related to the web page so the background page script doesn't have direct access to webpage `document` or events.

Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [fullscreenchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange) event (currently, it's under a vendor prefix):

```
addVendorEventListener(document, 'fullscreenchange', onFullscreenChange);

function onFullscreenChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

function addVendorEventListener(element, eventName, callback) {
    var vendorName = 'on' + eventName in element ? eventName
                   : 'onwebkit' + eventName in element ? 'webkit' + eventName
                   : 'onmoz' + eventName in element ? 'moz' + eventName
                   : null;
    if (vendorName)
        element.addEventListener(vendorName, callback);
}
```

manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
}],
```